# Fedora 37 Dual Boot | Not Enough Space for Grub.Img

Tags: linux, fedora, dualboot

Hey thanks for your help

It's been about 2 days asking random forums for help. **I'm just trying to do dual boot with Linux Fedora 37 KDE, here is the outline of what I've done so far.**

The drive where this is located is GPT formatted.

Created a 400GB partition on a D: drive (HDD), where C: (SSD) is where Windows 10 is.

The D: drive has another partition with data on it.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwYsp.png

Created a bootable USB using Fedora Image Writer (I have the same problem using Rufus as well)

When I start the Fedora OS, and click install. These are my errors:
Clicking the partitioned drive with the 400GB partition
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObjyM.png

After the automatic install I get an error that says "Error checking storage configuration"

Going to Custom Install and clicking, Automatically create partitions, gives me this error
"SDA may not have enough space for grub2 to embed core.img when using ext4 file system on partition"

*Someone told me what I need is efi partition with enough space, but I'm confused on how to do this.*

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on whether your Windows installation on the SSD is a UEFI/GPT one, as you would mostly want the Linux/grub installation to be of the same mode. You won't be able to chainload Windows with grub if they are of the same mode (but can only rely on the boot menu of the UEFI firmware to multi-boot).

It's kind of strange that the installer doesn't simply create the "BIOS boot partition" for you though. Such partition is required for BIOS/legacy (i386-pc) grub on GPT. Not sure if creating manually will help you get through the installation (in case you need it to be of BIOS/legacy mode because of your Windows installation). Not familiar with all those dumb distro installers.

But if your Windows is a UEFI/GPT one, what you need to do is to boot your installation medium in UEFI mode (it appears that now it is booted in legacy mode). You might need to make sure that the medium is properly written / prepared for UEFI booting as well. Once it is booted that way, the installer will likely use the existing EFI system partition on the SSD. If you want to avoid that, you might want to temporarily detach the SSD before you boot the installation medium and attach it back once you finished the installation. (Many distro installers are too dumb to offer an option for that.)